# modify item in obj javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying modify a item in obj (result of find in collection)

Collection

```
name: {},
date: {}
```

Example docs in collection

```
[
    {name: "pedro", date: "2018/01/01"},
    {name: "juan", date: "2018/02/02"}
]
```

Nodejs, mongoose

```
Collection.find().exec((err, result)=>{
    for(var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        result[i].date = "test";
    }
    res.send(result);
})
```

get route

```
[
    {name: "pedro", date: "2018/01/01"},
    {name: "juan", date: "2018/02/02"}
]
```

instead of what I expect

```
[
    {name: "pedro", date: "test"},
    {name: "juan", date: "test"}
]
```

I'm looking to make a new array of obj, but there are another way? Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: log what result is storing, you may find result has a property called data or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to convert mongoose documents into objects.

```
Collection.find().exec((err, result)=>{
    result = result.map(doc => doc.toObject()); // add this
    for(var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        result[i].date = "test";
    }
    res.send(result);
})
```

Also, there is another option: you can use mongoose `lean()` method to get plain objects instead of documents. This approach should have better performance than first one.

Here is short example of how might your query look like with `lean()`

```
Collection.find().lean().exec((err, result)=>{ // notice lean() before exec
    for(var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        result[i].date = "test";
    }
    res.send(result);
})
```

Learn more about `lean()` method [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)